# Recurrence relation for a given program

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Consider the following code :

```
def f(int A):
     if A<256 :
         return A^(1/2)
     B = A^(1/2)
     C = B^(1/2)
     return (f(B)+f(C))mod 16
```

Let T(n) denote the time complexity of this Algorithm. Time complexity is :

```
a) T(n) = T(n/2) + T(n/4) + O(1)
b) T(n) = T(n^(1/2)) + T(n^(1/4)) +O(1)
```

according to me, the answer should be (b) but it is given as (a). Why is this the answer, and where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We usually talk about the complexity of an algorithm with respect to it's *input size* (i.e. the length of it's *binary representation*), not the actual numerical value of the input.

So in this case the input size is `n = log(A)`, and the binary representations of `B` and `C` are `n / 2 = log(A) / 2 = log(A^(1/2)) = log(B)` and `n / 4 = log(C)` respectively. This gives us the relation in (a).